# Is c# code or script?

Tags: c#

Let's define languages like c,c++,java as code

Python,PHP as script.

Is c# code or script, and reason?

Comment: If you tell us your criteria for your groupings then maybe we could apply the same criteria to C#.

Comment: This has got to be a record setter for most identical answers in under a minute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most similar language to C# from your list is Java, so if you think Java is "code" then I guess C# is too.

But the idea that languages can be divided into "code" or "script" is a huge oversimplification in my opinion. For example, PHP can be either interpreted or compiled. Java can be compiled to bytecode which is then interpreted, or it can be [compiled directly to native code](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/). Python can be useful for small "scripting" tasks, but it can also be used to write enterprise class web applications.

Comment: Exactly. The distinction is even further obscured by JIT compiled "scripts" like Unladen Swallow. Also what about the "script" languages for the JVM which get compiled to bytecode like Groovy? :)

Comment: How about the other direction?  Java code can be compiled into JavaScript via GWT.  :)

Answer (score 4):

C# is a compiled language like java, C, and C++.  C# is code

Answer (score 3):

C# is code, compiled and strongly typed, very similar to Java in that respect.

C# is compiled to an intermediate language (MSIL), which in turn is compiled to machine code on a just-in-time basis.

Answer (score 3):

By that definition, it's "code" - as it's **compiled**, where as PHP / Python are **interpreted** at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Code - you compile C# code into binary executable files.

Answer (score 2):

C# is code (along with C, C++, Java, etc.). It gets compiled to CIL and then JIT compiled to machine code when you run the application.

Scripting languages are interpreted as they run. Think of Javascript running in the browser. As it is executed, it is interpreted by the Javascript engine that is executing it.

Answer (score 1):

Code.

Scripts can be interpreted (compiled) on the fly at runtime. C# can't (well, that can and may change one day).

Answer (score 1):

[C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) is a .NET programming language, quite similar to Java.

I don't understand the purpose of your question.

Answer (score 1):

C# would be closer to Java than C or C++.  But it's not a script language that is run through an interpreter like PHP.  But it's not a purely compiled language either, like C/C++ typically are.  C/C++ are compiled down to machine code that is executed directly by the CPU it's compiled for.  C# and Java are compiled down to an intermediate language (MSIL and Java byte code respectively) and are then run by a VM which usually JIT compiles it to the final CPU code.